# Rails Encrypted Credentials in a docker container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, credentials

I'm using rails 5.2 and trying to use ActiveStorage with `docker-compose`.

I set my `access_key_id` and `secret_key` with `EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit` on my local computer.

But I don't know how I can set those keys in a container.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you please share you contents of dockerfile

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`rails credentials:edit` produces/edits `config/credentials.yml.enc` which is encrypted and you can safely commit it along with your other code,
and this file along with code should end up inside the container.

Then you should set `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` environment variable when running the container and rails will be able to decrypt.

```
compose_target:
 image: 'your_image'
 environment:
   - RAILS_MASTER_KEY=here_goes_the_key_do_not_commit_it
```

or `docker run ... -e RAILS_MASTER_KEY=lala`

(just be sure this key is not leaked/commited in the same repository)